# Probability of $X^2>4$ if $X$ has the Cauchy distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If the density is : $p(x)=1/\pi(x^2+1)$ with $x \in\mathbb{R}$ 
1 question: 
 what is the probability $P[X^2>4]$?

I start the answer by

$$1- \displaystyle{\int_{-2}^{2}}p(x)dx=1-2(\tan^{-1}(2)/\pi)=0.30$$

2 questions :
If $ Y=X^2$ what is the law ?

My answer is I take $dy=2xdx$, so the law of density Y is :
$$g(y)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac1{1+y}\frac1{\sqrt{y}}$$ for $y \in\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: Why is the answer not $0.30$?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean to me Tad

Comment: The calculation you did answers the question you asked.